# Storing and deleting data recursively in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a blog component for a client's website and I'm having a bit of a problem with the data. I have a simple "content" table which holds the content for a blog entry. I'm reusing this table for comments on blog entries as the fields are all the same.

I have added a ParentID to the content table so that I can link comments to their parent content item. In order to ensure I don't get zombied content items I have added a trigger to delete any child content items when a content item gets deleted:

```
delete from content where ParentID in (select ID from deleted)
```

However, when I delete content items that don't even have any child content items I am getting an error from SQL Server (2008):

```
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).
```

The trigger should fire once for the deleted content but shouldn't be called again if the content has no children? Does anybody know why I am getting this error?

TIA

Comment: All due respect, and it doesn't answer your question directly, but having two separate tables would be a better design. Clearer, simpler, and probably would perform better for most types of database interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the a set-based solution for that:

```
WITH    h AS
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    content
        WHERE   id = @row_to_delete
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  c.id
        FROM    h
        JOIN    content c
        ON      c.parentID = h.id
        )
DELETE
FROM    content
WHERE   id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    h
        )
```

To make sure that no orphan rows are ever left, create a fake common ancestor with hardcoded `id` and parent equal to that `id`:

```
INSERT
INTO    content (id, parentid)
VALUES  (0, 0)

ALTER TABLE content
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_content_parent_self
FOREIGN KEY (parentId)
REFERENCES content (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the trigger to only perform the delete if rows exist

```
DECLARE @ID int
SELECT @ID = TOP 1 ID from content where ParentID in (select ID from deleted)
IF (@ID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    delete from content where ParentID in (select ID from deleted)
END
```

Comment: thanks Matt, I actually came to a similar conclusion using IF EXISTS - typical, I always come up with a solution as soon as I ask the question!! Thanks for the reply though, appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, that happens all the time - I think writing out your question makes you think about it more clearly...